# Get Value from knex-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having following function - from the library knex - that returns a promise:

```
function findById(id) {
    knex('posts').select().where('id', id).first().then(data => {
        return data
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

const id = 1
        console.log("Post with " + id + ": " + service.findById(parseInt(id)))
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Post with 1: undefined
ReferenceError: id is not defined
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? Did I created the callback of the promise false?

Appreciate your replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return value in `promise` in javascript.

Why?

Because `promise` is asynchronized.

The execution sequence of the program would thus be

```
console.log("Post with " + id + ": " + undefined) //Because promise haven't return value yet
knex('posts').select().where('id', id).first().then(data => {
        return data
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

What you can do here is do something in the then block.

```
function findById(id) {
    knex('posts').select().where('id', id).first().then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

If you want to separate the logic outside, you can pass an callback function:

```
function findById(id, callback) {
    knex('posts').select().where('id', id).first().then(data => {
        callback(data)
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

const id = 1
service.findById(parseInt(id), (data)=>{
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues here.

The first is you are missing a return statement on your `findById` function, without which `findById` will always return `undefined`.

Below is the function with a return.

```
function findById(id) {
    return knex('posts')
         .select()
         .where('id', id)
         .first()
         .then(data => {
            return data
         })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Also, you'll need to use `findById` itself in a promise, so that you know that the value has asynchronously resolved before you call it.

Try this for the higher-level calls which invoke `findById`:

```
const id = 1
service.findById(parseInt(id))
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("Post with " + id + ": " + result);
    });
```